# Overriding an UpdateView's get_form_kwargs() method

Tags: python, django

I'd like to override an UpdateView's `get_form_kwargs()` method, and have something similar to the following:

```
class GroupRatingView(UpdateView):
    model = Group
    fields = ['rating']

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(GroupRatingView, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

However, if I try this out, I get the following error:

```
File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  181.         form = self.get_form()

File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_form
  45.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

Exception Type: TypeError at /groups/5/rate
Exception Value: ModelFormMetaclass object argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType
```

It seems that `self.get_form_kwargs()` is returning `None`, whereas I would expect to drop into the debugger. Why am I getting an error instead of hitting the debugger trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to return the `kwargs` at the end of the method; this causes the method to return `None`, which is not a mapping and causes the error.

Add a `return` statement to your method:

```
class GroupRatingView(UpdateView):
    ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(GroupRatingView, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
        return kwargs
```